# WHMCS API: How to override domain price?

Tags: whmcs

I couldn't get a response [here](http://forum.whmcs.com/showthread.php?98299-WHMCS-API-How-to-override-domain-price). So I figured I'd ask on good ol' reliable stackoverflow.

When you do a call to WHMCS, you can override prices for products:

"priceoverride[0]" = 333;

However, this does not work for domains. The documentation states:

"priceoverride - allows you to pass in a custom price override for the product (domains are not products)"

So, how is one supposed to override the domain price. I have certain "premium domains" that cost most than normal domains and I need to be able to include them on an order with their own price.

Therefore... this wont work:
- Creating an invoice for the domain only means there will be two invoices
- Merging the invoices without sending them sounds like a lot of effort for a field that should just be supported for domains as well

How can I get around this?

Comment: Did you find out anything? Got nearly the same problem...

Comment: No reply yet. But will be working on it this week and probably open a ticket with WHMCS. Will report back if I find out anything.

Comment: So in case it's not clear, dont use "priceoverride", use "domainpriceoverride".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hook OrderDomainPricingOverride can help:

http://docs.whmcs.com/Hooks:OrderDomainPricingOverride

As the cart page is being displayed, this hook is run separately for each Domain added to the cart. You can change price for each of them

Comment: So in case it's not clear, dont use "priceoverride", use "domainpriceoverride".